# Modificando um Script (JS) de terceiros/externo

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout-responsivo

Preciso usar um script externo que gera um formulário (até ai tudo bem, ele está funcionando) ... Uma vez o script inserido na página, preciso que os labels do formulário (gerados pelo script) fiquem responsíveis (creio que com um **window.onresize**) ... Mas como faço isso, sendo que não tenho acesso ao script que gera o formulário?

Coloquei window.onresize na pagina mas ele não surte efeito ao formulário.

---

[image: Exemplo]

Coloquei em um HTML um script que gera um formulário...
O formulário em si funciona, mas eu precisava deixar os labels dele responsiveis

Criei um script de `window.onresize` e apontei o `getElementbyId` para o ID da div do script que quero mudar, mas ele da erro

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('hot-spot-isc-0faaa9d5ee2e31146d01').innerHTML = document.body.offsetWidth;

}
window.onresize = function(){
    document.getElementById('hot-spot-isc-0faaa9d5ee2e31146d01').innerHTML = document.body.offsetWidth;

    var bodyWidth = document.body.offsetWidth;
    if( bodyWidth>800 )
        fs = ( bodyWidth-800 )/10;
    else
        fs = 0;

    document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].style.fontSize = (fs+20)+'px';
    document.body.style.fontSize = (fs+12)+'px';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Podes ser mais específico? sem saber qual o HTML é dificil ajudar. Talvez seja possivel fazer isso somente com CSS...

Comment: @Sergio respondi a baixo

Comment: Qual é o erro que dá

Comment: Não entendi exatamente qual é o erro. Mas utilizar o [Media Rule](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) do CSS pode ser uma solução viável.

Comment: Opa, já pensou em usar o bootstrap para fazer todo esse trabalho por você? Se não, fica a dica:
https://getbootstrap.com Forte abraço.